# Search data from API using ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to fetch data from an API using as a parameter ID of a post from that API.
I created this app:

```js
 

   import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const GetData = () => {
        let [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState('');
        let [idApi, setidApi] = useState("");
        let [res, setRes] = useState('loading...');


        function searchInfo(e) {
            setInputVal(e.target.value);
            // console.log(inputVal);
        }

        useEffect(() => {
            getInfo();
            console.log("re")
        }, [idApi])
        const getInfo = () => {
            const fetchData = async () => {
                setidApi(inputVal)
                const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${idApi}`);
                const data = await response.json();
                const r = data[0].title;
                setRes(r);
                console.log(r)
            };
            fetchData();
        };


        return (
            <div>
                <p>{res}</p>
                <input onChange={searchInfo} type="text" className='input-search'/>
                <button onClick={getInfo}>Fetch</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
;

export default GetData;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Clicking on the button i want to set the `idApi` using the input value (`inputVal`), and to get the `data` what will correspond with the setted ID. For this i wrote this code: `setidApi(inputVal)`, but it doesn't work. Who can explain how to solve the issue?

Comment: At first glance it looks like you are using `idApi` before it has a value populated from state. You also aren't using the useEffect hook

Answer (score 0):

You have to change order for setting value then calling api like below:

```
const getInfo = () => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          setidApi(inputVal)
            const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${idApi}`);
            const data = await response.json();

            console.log(data)
        };
        fetchData();
    };
```

Comment: State updates are asynchronous. In this case it's possible `idApi` would not update before the fetch call.

Comment: Here idApi set through inputval on onchange event so final whatever in the search it should be set when clicked. I think state set when inputvalue with value to set. Now AskMen can answer if anything else :)

Comment: @Niraj, i changed the code, but when i type a number in my input i get the next error: `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`

Comment: Check your api response